# Compiling code only for the iOS 8.1 SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8.1

I want to conditionally compile some code when building with the iOS 8.1 SDK, and compile some different code when using the 8.0 SDK. In a small project that targets the 8.1 SDK (and can use APIs new to 8.1), it appears that the `#if` directive ignores constants.

```
println("__IPHONE_8_1 is defined to be \(__IPHONE_8_1)")
#if __IPHONE_8_1
    println("8.1")
    #else
    println("8.0")
#endif
```

The above code prints:

```
__IPHONE_8_1 is defined to be 80100
8.0
```

According to the documentation on [conditional compilation statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20),

> Swift code can be conditionally compiled based on the evaluation of
>   build configurations. Build configurations include the literal `true`
>   and `false` values, command line flags, and the platform-testing
>   functions listed in the table below. You can specify command line
>   flags using `-D <#flag#>`.

It then talks about `os()` and `arch()` functions but has nothing about SDK versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Swift does not support referencing constants from conditional compilation predicates. My solution for this specific case is to define different compiler flags depending on the SDK version.

Under Xcode's build settings, go to Other Swift Flags where you can set flags for different SDKs. Since my Xcode installation was not associated with both the 8.0 and 8.1 SDKs, I edited the project.pbxproj file by hand:

```
"OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[sdk=iphoneos8.1]" = "-D DEBUG -D __IPHONE_8_1";
"OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[sdk=iphoneos8.0]" = "-D DEBUG";
```

In Xcode it looks like:

[image]